# Menu is not opening a correct index div

Tags: reactjs

Guy's I m facing a problem. I have a 2-dimensional data. The data has a nested structure that contains links.

```
const data = [
  // First Div Panel 
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      url: "/services",
      title: "Services"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Products",
      children: [
        {
          id: 3,
          url: "/themes-templates",
          title: "Themes & Templates"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          url: "/open-source",
          title: "Open Source"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          url: "/solutions",
          title: "Solutions"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      url: "/work",
      title: "Work",
      children: [
        {
          id: 7,
          url: "/methodology",
          title: "Methodology",
          children: [
            {
              id: 8,
              url: "/agile",
              title: "Agile",
              children: [
                {
                  id: 9,
                  url: "/scrum",
                  title: "Scrum"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      url: "/contact-us",
      title: "Contact Us"
    }
  ],
  // Second Div Panel which contains children of second list item
  [
    {
      id: 3,
      url: "/themes-templates",
      title: "Themes & Templates"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      url: "/open-source",
      title: "Open Source"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      url: "/solutions",
      title: "Solutions"
    }
  ],
  // Third Div Panel which contains children of third list item
  [
    {
      id: 7,
      url: "/methodology",
      title: "Methodology",
      children: [
        {
          id: 8,
          url: "/agile",
          title: "Agile",
          children: [
            {
              id: 9,
              url: "/scrum",
              title: "Scrum"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  // Fourth Div Panel contains the children of the 3rd sub list item
  [
    {
      id: 8,
      url: "/agile",
      title: "Agile",
      children: [
        {
          id: 9,
          url: "/scrum",
          title: "Scrum"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  // Fourth Div Panel contains the children of the 3rd sub sub list item
  [
    {
      id: 9,
      url: "/scrum",
      title: "Scrum"
    }
  ]
];
```

My task is to utilize that 2-dimensional data and create a mobile menu in `react` that has a push panel-like structure.

Nevertheless, I try to create like this. What I did is I treated every sub-array as a separate panel `div`. First, sub-array items will be considered on the root panel which is by default visible. If an item has a `children` property then it means a dynamically `next` button is generated on that list item. When we click on this button, it will add an `is-visible` class on the panel. But, the question is **how it will track which panel is associated with that button click**? I try to use a state with `activeId` and `prevId` But my indexing is not correctly working and not opening a correct panel. You can inspect my solution on the chrome inspector panel. I appreciate it if you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[My code sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/panel-menu-3hcf4)

**Code:**

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

//#region Data
const data = [
  // First Div Panel
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      url: "/services",
      title: "Services"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Products",
      children: [
        {
          id: 3,
          url: "/themes-templates",
          title: "Themes & Templates"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          url: "/open-source",
          title: "Open Source"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          url: "/solutions",
          title: "Solutions"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      url: "/work",
      title: "Work",
      children: [
        {
          id: 7,
          url: "/methodology",
          title: "Methodology",
          children: [
            {
              id: 8,
              url: "/agile",
              title: "Agile",
              children: [
                {
                  id: 9,
                  url: "/scrum",
                  title: "Scrum"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      url: "/contact-us",
      title: "Contact Us"
    }
  ],
  // Second Div Panel
  [
    {
      id: 3,
      url: "/themes-templates",
      title: "Themes & Templates"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      url: "/open-source",
      title: "Open Source"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      url: "/solutions",
      title: "Solutions"
    }
  ],
  // Third Div Panel
  [
    {
      id: 7,
      url: "/methodology",
      title: "Methodology",
      children: [
        {
          id: 8,
          url: "/agile",
          title: "Agile",
          children: [
            {
              id: 9,
              url: "/scrum",
              title: "Scrum"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  // Fourth Div Panel
  [
    {
      id: 8,
      url: "/agile",
      title: "Agile",
      children: [
        {
          id: 9,
          url: "/scrum",
          title: "Scrum"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  // Fifth Div Panel
  [
    {
      id: 9,
      url: "/scrum",
      title: "Scrum"
    }
  ]
];
//#endregion Data

//#region Component


const PanelMenu = props => {
  const { title } = props;

  const [items, setItems] = useState(data);

  // Title Header of the Panel
  const [headerTitle, setHeaderTitle] = useState(title ? title : "");
  // Previous Title Header of the Panel
  const [prevHeaderTitle, setPrevHeaderTitle] = useState(title ? title : "");
  // ActiveIndex => 0 means by default master-panel is active
  const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(0);
  // PreviousIndex
  const [prevId, setPrevId] = useState(0);

  const handlePanelBtn = (newTitle, index, prevIndex) => {
    // Title Checking
    const titleProp = title ? title : "";
    const prevTitle = index === 0 ? titleProp : headerTitle;
    // SetStates
    setPrevHeaderTitle(prevTitle);
    setHeaderTitle(newTitle);
    setActiveId(index);
    setPrevId(prevIndex);
  };

  const panelRenderer = () => {
    const panelsJSX = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      let childItemIndex = i;
      const panels = (
        <div
          key={i}
          id={i === 0 ? "p__master" : `p__student-${i}`}
          className={
            childItemIndex === activeId
              ? "p__panel is-visible"
              : "p__panel is-hide"
          }
        >
          <ul>
            {items[i].map((item, index) => {
              // It means it have children
              if (item.children && item.children.length > 0) {
                childItemIndex++;
                return (
                  <li key={item.id} className="p-next">
                    {item.url ? (
                      <a href={item.url} className="p-link">
                        {item.title}
                      </a>
                    ) : (
                      <div className="p-link">{item.title}</div>
                    )}
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="p-next__btn"
                      data-id={`#p__student-${childItemIndex}`}
                      onClick={() => handlePanelBtn(item.title, index, prevId)}
                    >
                      <span>&gt;</span>
                    </button>
                  </li>
                );
              } else {
                return (
                  <li key={item.id}>
                    <a href={item.url} className="p-link">
                      {item.title}
                    </a>
                  </li>
                );
              }
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );

      panelsJSX.push(panels);
    }
    return panelsJSX;
  };

  const renderer = () => {
    if (items && items.length > 0) {
      return (
        <div className="p">
          <div className="p__wrap">
            {/* Panel Actions => Header */}
            <div className="p__actions">
              {/* Previous Button */}

              {activeId !== 0 && (
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="p-action__btn left"
                  onClick={() =>
                    handlePanelBtn(prevHeaderTitle, prevId, prevId)
                  }
                >
                  <span>&lt;</span>
                </button>
              )}

              {/* Title */}
              {headerTitle && (
                <div className="p-action__title">{headerTitle}</div>
              )}

              {/* Close Button */}
              <button type="button" className="p-action__btn right">
                <span>×</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            {/* Panel children Wrapper */}
            <div className="p__children">{panelRenderer()}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
  return <React.Fragment>{renderer()}</React.Fragment>;
};

//#endregion Component



// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <PanelMenu title="Menu" />,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

```html
<style>

*,:before,:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.p__wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 320px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    z-index: 1;
    color: #333;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.p__actions {
    position: relative;
    padding: 14px;
    min-height: 54px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}

.p-action__title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.p-action__btn {
    position: absolute;
    width: 54px;
    height: 54px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #333;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.left {
    left: 0;
}

.right {
    right: 0;
}

.p__children {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: calc(100% - 54px);
}

.p__panel {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease 0s;
}

.p__panel.is-visible {
    transform: translateX(0);
    z-index: 1;
}

.p__panel.is-hide {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.p__panel > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.p__panel > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}
.p__panel > ul > li > .p-link {
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 14px 24px;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}



.p__panel > ul > li > .p-link:hover {
   background-color: #dcdcdc;
}

.p-next {
    position: relative;
}

.p-next__btn {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    color: #333;
    border: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    cursor: pointer;
}

</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and transformed your code into a working example in the following code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/panel-menu-hfrmx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

It may seem like a lot of changes at first, so I'll elaborate a bit:

- I extracted the menu header and the menu item list into their own components allowing for easier reuse
- I rewrote your data structure, so that you don't need to define the menu items twice or even three times. This structure is flat, which also allows you to easily store it in a database might you want that.

Comment: I will check that.

Comment: It's a nice idea to first flatten the array with the correct parent `index` and then generate this menu. By the way, data is coming from an external API. But using your approach is really helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: Appreciate that it is helpful. If it solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted. Otherwise, let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: What is the best approach to save hierarchical data structure in javascript? Do we have to nested children inside a one-dimensional array or We have to flatten the array with objects which have a reference to the parent id? What did you suggest?

Comment: That depends on the use case. If you are sure that you'll only use the data once and if performance is critical, then there is something to say for storing it in its hierarchical form. However, if you might use the same data in different ways, then I think that it is often easiest to store it as flat as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need

`handlePanelBtn(item.title, childItemIndex, prevId)`

instead of

`handlePanelBtn(item.title, index, prevId)`

https://codesandbox.io/s/panel-menu-2uwxo

Comment: In your codesandbox When I click the `products` list-item `next` button. It is not opening children of the `products` list item.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with context api to simplify your logic of showing panel.

Create context called PanelContext which has panel array which can be used to show current panel and go back in the menu.

```
import React from "react";

export const PanelContext = React.createContext();
export function PanelProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentPanel, setCurrentPanel] = React.useState([0]);
  const addItemToPanel = item => setCurrentPanel(prev => [item, ...prev]);
  const goBack = () => setCurrentPanel(prev => prev.slice(1));
  return (
    <PanelContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentPanel: currentPanel[0],
        setCurrentPanel: addItemToPanel,
        goBack
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </PanelContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

and created panel component which will recursively create all panel and show panel which is active based on context value.

```
const Panel = ({ items, id, title }) => {
  const { currentPanel, setCurrentPanel, goBack } = React.useContext(
    PanelContext
  );
  const panels = [];
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={id === currentPanel ? "p__wrap visible" : " p__wrap hidden"}
      >
        <h2>
          {title && <button onClick={goBack}>{"<"}</button>} {title || "Menu"}{" "}
        </h2>
        <div className="p__panel">
          <ul>
            {items.map(item => {
              if (item.children)
                panels.push(
                  <Panel
                    title={item.title}
                    id={item.id}
                    items={item.children}
                  />
                );
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
                  <li>
                    {item.title}
                    {item.children && (
                      <button
                        onClick={() => {
                          setCurrentPanel(item.id);
                        }}
                      >
                        {">"}
                      </button>
                    )}
                  </li>
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      {panels}
    </>
  );
};
export const PanelMenu = props => {
  return (
    <PanelProvider>
      <Panel items={data} id={0} />
    </PanelProvider>
  );
};
```

I have broke your css.

and used only one object with deeply nested children.

Here is working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/panel-menu-c871j

Comment: Thanks for the answer really appreciate that.